# Did my post baptism absolve my sin of abortion?

Tags: confession, abortion

In my 20’s, my mom made me abort a child. Later, I was baptized Protestant. I went through RCIA. Did my baptism absolve my sin or must I confess?

Comment: What's RCIA? The Catholic Rite of Christian Initiation of Adults?

Comment: _Like any library, Christianity Stack Exchange offers great information, but does not offer personalized advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your pastor, priest, or other trustworthy counselor._

Comment: Could you detail your history a little better.  Pastoral advice is really not something we offer here - if you're worried about absolution of your personal sins, you can ask pastor about that.  Here we can give you doctrines that might help fill in the blanks.  But I'm not sure if you're a Catholic or a Protestant by the words in the question.

Comment: Also, if your mom, "made you have an abortion" it is not your sin, by the Catholic understanding of things - although don't bet your salvation on the words of an Internet Chump like myself.

Comment: Don't look to your baptism or anything YOU do.. look to Jesus dying on the cross for your sins.. believe he took the full punishment for all your sins.. read John's Gospel and believe on God's remedy for guilt, Jesus Christ the Righteous One.

Answer (score 1):

Protestantism covers a rather wide spectrum of beliefs, so it's difficult to give a definitive answer.

That said, Protestantism generally does not designate the enumeration of specific sins as a requirement for Salvation. Rather, God requires *repentance*. If you are sorry for your sins and repent of them before God, that is what is most important. Many (most?) Protestants also offer *general, corporate* confession and absolution as part of their worship services. At least some Protestant pastors also hear private confessions. (IMNSHO, if your pastor *doesn't*, I would seek a different pastor/church.)

If you confess and repent before God, and especially if you've received absolution (including general, corporate absolution), you're good in most/all Protestant views.

More generally... **you** can do nothing for your sin(s), but Christ already did *everything*. The 'onus' on *you* is merely to accept what Christ has done. If you're holding on to a sin, not repenting of it, then you aren't accepting Grace. You do not, however, need to undertake specific actions to receive absolution; it is a free gift.

**That said**, if a particular sin concerns or is bothering you, I would strongly encourage you to seek private confession. There is (usually¹) nothing *wrong* with doing so, and you may find it beneficial. The right purpose of private confession and even penance (provided it is not taken to an extent that it becomes harmful) are not that these are "required", but that they may be beneficial to you.

(¹ If, like Luther, you find yourself compelled to confess constantly to every sin, no matter how trivial, your pastor may encourage you to stop doing that...)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, baptism removes all sin, [original](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=35322) and [actual](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=31649), as well as all [temporal punishment](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=36796) due to those sins.

The [*Catechism of the Council of Trent* (*Tridentine* or *Roman Catechism*)](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5864), [when discussing baptism](http://www.catholicapologetics.info/thechurch/catechism/Holy7Sacraments-Baptism.shtml), gives these [effects of this great sacrament](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/TP/TP069.html#TPQ69OUTP1):

1. Remission Of Sin
2. Remission Of All Punishment Due To Sin
3. Grace Of Regeneration
4. Infused Virtues And Incorporation With Christ
5. Character Of Christian

You are, however, free to confess already forgiven sins and [venial sins](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=37060) to a priest (although one is only required to confess [mortal sins](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34987)); cf. the [*Catechism of the Council of Trent* on penance/confession](http://www.catholicapologetics.info/thechurch/catechism/Holy7Sacraments-Penance.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

Baptism should follow the event of the spiritual new birth (see John chapter 3). It should be a declaration of one having put their faith in Jesus Christ for the remission of sins. Baptism is a sort-of "nailing one's colours to the cross" (not, the mast).  By being baptised, one is effectively agreeing with what Jesus said, that they are picking up their cross daily in order to follow Jesus (Matthew 16:24). They will identify themselves with Christ's cross and all the shame, ridicule and persecution that is inclined to bring.

Now, having said that,it should be clear that nobody should get baptised without first appreciating what Christ's crucifixion accomplished for all who put their faith in his finished work on the cross. What he accomplished had a great deal to do with how God has justly dealt with sin, pouring out all wrath and deserved judgment on sin upon the sinless Son of God - Jesus Christ.

The Protestant *Westminster Confession of Faith* under chapter XXVIII, Baptism, says this sacrament is (amongst other things) to be "a sign and a seal of [the one baptised] his ingrafting into Christ, of regeneration, of remission of sins, and of his giving up unto God through Jesus Christ, to walk in newness of life..."

The baptised believer is now "in Christ" by faith and the indwelling of the Holy Spirit (read the first half of Romans chapter 8). The person is regenerated - newness of life has miraculously happened (as per John chapter 3). Sins are remitted (as in Jesus' words, "this is my blood of the new testament, which is shed for many for the remission of sins", John 26:28 & read Acts 2:37-39.)

This site is not for giving personal advice so I will say nothing further, other than that a study these Bible texts will help anyone wishing to grasp the connection between baptism and remission of sins.

Comment: Missing disclaimer: the position you describe is very credobaptist and paedobaptist denominations would take exception to it. (Also, I don't think it really answers the Question.)

Comment: @Matthew  The OP stated,' Later, I was baptized Protestant', so a Protestant-based answer is called for. This site does not want answers that advise a person in the way the OP hopes for, so only in that respect I did not fully answer. While much that I say is clearly about baptism of non-infants, the Westminster Confession that I quoted from holds to paedo-baptism, so I covered both aspects.

Comment: "Protestant" and "credobaptist" are hardly synonymous.